# Android - Firebase; on signing in, retrieve data (layered) and redirect that user based on that data

Tags: android, firebase, layered

So I have a simple firebase android application, which I'm aiming to cater for a number of different users. 
A user registers, and on creation, their Uid is stored in a user table, along with a UserInformation entry under their Uid with the values 'UserType' and 'IsCurrentlyTracking'.
A user signs in, is brought to a Profile activity where they can press a button to continue on through the app.
Here is my table structure:

On pressing continue, their UserInformation data is retrieved. Based on that data, they are redirected to another activity. 
Instead of doing the aforementioned, the application stops/crashes.

Here is the code/method that redirects the user:

```
public void userRedirect(){

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    Query q = database.getReference("Users/" + user.getUid() + "/UserInformation");

    q.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                UserInformation uI = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
                int userType = uI.getUserType();
                boolean ICT = uI.getTrackingStatus();

                if ((userType == 1) && (!ICT)) {

                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, AllocationActivity.class));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            databaseError.getMessage();
        }
    });
}
```

I have been able to retrieve data before, although the information was not stored in a 'Users' table (only under the user's UiD), nor did UserInformation descend from the UiD.

For some extra context, here is my user class:

```
public int UserType;
public boolean IsCurrentlyTracking;

public UserInformation(int userType, boolean IsCurrentlyTracking){
    this.UserType = userType;
    this.IsCurrentlyTracking = IsCurrentlyTracking;
}

public int getUserType()
{
    return UserType;
}

public boolean getTrackingStatus()
{
    return IsCurrentlyTracking;
}
```

Any ideas on where I might be going wrong? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use FirebaseUI for authentication and get a reference to the uid. I also suggest you don't use "+" to concatenate Firebase paths. Try this instead:

```
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

...

DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseAuth
                .getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).getRef();
```

and add a listener like this:

```
listener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // handle UserInformation here
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

databaseReference.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

The reason I prefer separating it instead of overriding it inside the method is that then I can do the following in onDestroy:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        databaseReference.removeEventListener(listener);
    }
```

Keeping DatabaseReference and listener as member variables makes this easier.

Also, be sure to set appropriate Firebase rules for hardening a users access to only their data:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    }
  }
}
```

For a more complete example, check out a todo list app I made which uses the same database organization pattern [here](https://github.com/farazfazli/todo-demo). Hope I was able to help, feel free to comment if you have any other questions or if something was unclear.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Faraz. I'll restructure and see how I get on. Also, thanks for the access hardening in the database rules.